# Create and initialize cell array

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a decent way to create and initialize a cell array with a given value. I can think of the following oneliner

```
val = 'hello';
dim = [2, 4, 6];
arrayfun(@(x) val, zeros(dim), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

but I feel dirty.

Comment: What does decent mean? Faster, fewer lines or...?

Comment: It means cleaner that my above solution. Yes, clean code is also a vague concept, but still an arguably useful one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler alternative:

```
C = repmat({val}, dim);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid `arrayfun`, you could do

```
C = cell(dim);
C(:) = {val};
```

or

```
C = cell(dim);
[C{:}] = deal(val);
```

Comment: O.o Oh... deal()... Thats quite useful! +1