# How to Access the Cell array Matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Could any one tell me about the indexing of a cell Array? I've tried to google it but I could only find unsatisfied result (may be I'm not good in googling). For matrix indexing I found a good document which can be found [here](http://matlabtricks.com/post-23/tutorial-on-matrix-indexing-in-matlab). For my case let take a simple example.

```
a = {ones(10)}
```

and I want to access the first element of `a`. Something like

```
a(1,1) % this will give a 10 x 10 matrix but i am not looking for it.
```

I can do it by changing it into a matrix like

```
a = cell2mat(a);
a(1,1)
ans = 1
```

but is there any direct way to access first element of cell array sub matrix.

Comment: When nothing else works, read the manual/help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html (don't forget to also check out "For more information" section)

Comment: Dear @Oleg Komarov Thanks for reply. i read it but i could not find what acctually i was looking for...........

Comment: @user2851655 see the end of the answer in the duplicate question. You just call `()` after `{}` as in `a{1}(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the first element of a the first cell in a cell array, you may do:

```
a = {ones(10)};
a{1}(1)
```

If you have multidimensional cell arrays, with multidimensional numerical arrays inside it, you can do:

```
a{2,3}(4,5)
```

This will give you element (4,5) of cell (2,3).

Comment: Thanks a lot i was actually looking for this kind of answer. Thank you ...........

Answer (score 2):

You actually are accessing the first element of `a`, and it contains a matrix of 10×10 filled with ones.

Initializing a cell can be done by `a = cell(10)`, and obtaining a certain value of the cell matrix is done with `a{i,j}`. See also the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

---

For initializing a cell array with some values, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282059/create-and-initialize-cell-array).

Comment: In order to access elements of elements of a cell array, single-level indexing is not enough. `a{1,1}(1,1)` is rather the answer.

Comment: That is just how you interpret the question. Accessing the first value in the array that is in the first element of a cell is done like that. Anyway, you do have a point.

Comment: @Jan de Gier. Thanks a lot Dear and i really appriciate for your help. but i was looking for somthing like **Robert** ans.... THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS